# Keep an image same size as HTML markup but div is 16:9 ratio

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div mask that hides part of the image that extends beyond 16:9 ratio.

I've tried a lot of things found on here, but they seem to just focus on if the img is included in CSS, or if you're using it as a full screen image.

I have a few images that are 4:3 ratio, but our new site has a standard of all featured images being 16:9 ratio. I've tried the "youtube/vimeo" embed:

`div {padding-top: 56.25%; position: relative; overflow:hidden;}`

`div img {position: absolute; top:0;left:0; width:100%; height:100%; }`

However neither of these solve my problem. [Here is the closest I can get to duplicating my code.](http://codepen.io/ishio/pen/ZGJNvj)

Any suggestions? I can't do object-fit due to compatibility. This is being done via WordPress. CSS would be preferred as my developers frown upon me using any javascript. Also setting widths to px wouldn't be a solution for me either due to responsiveness changes the already 16:9's height and width. It obviously changes as I scale up or down.

Answer (score 0):

Bahhhhh I'm an idiot.

I ended up using

`div.img-container { display: block; height: 0; padding-bottom: 56.25%; overflow: hidden; }`

And kept the image at `max-width: 100%; height: auto;`